# HtmlCleaner returns "???" when parsing non-english web site

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, htmlcleaner

When I try to parse websites like [Google](http://www.google.com) or [Apple](http://www.apple.com) with [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) everything goes fine.
But when I try to parse a Chinese web site the text looks like this "???".

What causes this problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: Where do you see ??? in the text? Are yo printing it on the console? Are you saving it to a file? Can you show us some of the source code?

Answer (score 2):

character encoding issue.You need to set the encoding based on the contents before doing anything on content.

Comment: I suggest you improve your response (which was flagged as "low quality post" by somebody) a bit, i.e. explain where the encoding is in HTML, and how to set the encoding.